# Is Wikipedia a good source of taxonomy?

Tags: genetics, evolution, botany, zoology, taxonomy

I have been quite interested in biology lately,and I would like to know whether it is a good choice to look up taxonomic information there.

Comment: totally depends. Depends on 1) if you want Linean vs phylogenetic taxonomy, 2) organism of interest, 3) taxonomic rank of interest, 3) area of the world, 4) how well-known/studied/interesting a taxonomic group is, 5) how complex or unclear the phylogenetics are, 6) how up-to-date or accurately stitched together the Wikipedia page is, 7) what sources (and their age + reception) are used to inform the Wikipedia page,  etc...

Comment: Perhaps equally important is: *why do you care*? If this is for any formal, professional, academic, or research-focused interest, then I'd say no. If you're simply curious how the world is all organized or learning about different groups of organisms then I'd say Wikipedia is more than adequate most of the time. Just go into it realizing it's not perfect or consistent, so sometimes you need to use outside (reputable) sources to help better inform what you're looking at.

Comment: Thank you! I am only a 15 year old student,so it is not for formal interest.:)